# Show that $ {x}_{k+1} - {x}_{k} \rightarrow L \Rightarrow \frac {{x}_{k}} { k} \rightarrow L $

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, limits

I have to show that the implication in the title is true as

$ k \rightarrow \infty $ and where $ \left< {x}_{k} \right> $ is a sequence

This question is from Wade's Introduction to Analysis and I think that it is something to do with Cauchy sequences because right before the question it says "[Cauchy]". However, the book doesn't give any hints or anything on how to prove it.

$ {x}_{k+1}- {x}_{k} -L \rightarrow 0$ as $ k \rightarrow \infty $

is a Cauchy sequence

$ \Rightarrow \frac {{x}_{k+1} - {x}_{k} - L} {k} \rightarrow 0 $ as $ k \rightarrow \infty $

is a Cauchy sequence as well.

Another way I was thinking about it is

$ lim _{k \rightarrow \infty} {{x}_{k}} = lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} ( {x}_{k+1} - L) $

so it would be sufficient to show that

$ lim _{k \rightarrow \infty} \frac {{x}_{k+1} - L}  {k} = L$

However, I'm not sure how to follow through on either in order to show the implication.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Notice that this is a special case of the Stolz-Cesaro Theorem, with $b_k=k$ for all k: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For every $\epsilon > 0$ there is $K > 0$ such that for $k \geq K$ we have $|x_{k+1}-x_k-L| < \epsilon$. Notice that for $n > k$ we have
$$
x_n = (x_n - x_{n-1}) + (x_{n-1} - x_{n-2}) + \cdots + (x_{K+1} - x_K) + x_K.
$$
Using the bound $|x_{k+1}-x_k-L| < \epsilon$ we can deduce that
$$
|x_n-nL+KL-x_K| = |x_n-(n-K)L-x_K| < (n-K)\epsilon.
$$
Therefore
$$
\left| \frac{x_n}{n} - L \right| \leq \frac{K|L| + |x_K|}{n} + \epsilon.
$$
Let $N = \frac{K|L| + |x_K|}{\epsilon}$. For $n \geq N$, the calculation above shows that
$$
\left| \frac{x_n}{n} - L \right| \leq 2\epsilon.
$$
Since this is true for any $\epsilon > 0$, we conclude that $\frac{x_n}{n} \to L$.